# ColdFusion local scope inside object literal

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm seeing some weird behaviour when using CF's local scope in an object literal, in function arguments. But only when executed inside a loop...

Example code:

```
<cffunction name="f">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset LOCAL.foo = 123 />       

        <!--- Works fine --->
        #serializeJSON({blah = LOCAL.foo})#

        <!--- Works fine --->
        <cfloop from=1 to=1 index="i">
            <cfset bar = {blah = LOCAL.foo} />
            #serializeJSON(bar)#
        </cfloop>

        <!--- Element FOO is undefined in LOCAL --->
        <cfloop from=1 to=1 index="i">  
            #serializeJSON({blah = LOCAL.foo})#
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</cffunction>


<cfset f() />
```

PS: `serializeJSON()` is just for example purposes. This is happening in any function I've tested where one of the arguments is a struct.

Comment: So, what is the "weird behavior"?

Comment: "Element FOO is undefined in LOCAL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works just fine in Railo.

It also doesn't make any difference if using any other container instead of `local` scope, also it's impossible to catch this with `cftry`.

If you serialize just local scope within the loop:

```
<cfloop from=1 to=1 index="i">
    #serializeJSON(local)#
</cfloop>
```

Result is:

```
{"ARGUMENTS":{},"___IMPLICITARRYSTRUCTVAR1":{"BLAH":123},"___IMPLICITARRYSTRUCTVAR0":{"BLAH":123},"FOO":123}
```

Looks like a bug. Mind [filing](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=newBug)?

Answer (score 1):

`LOCAL` is a scope used only within functions. If you try to create a `LOCAL` scope variable outside of a function, it will fail.

I will write up a test and prove it to you in a minute....

**UPDATE** Actually, I have CF 8 at work and can't test it.

In CF8 and below, you can set `LOCAL.Foo`, but it's not really a CF scope.

In CF9 and above, `LOCAL` can be set only within a function.

```
<cffunction>
   <cfset LOCAL.foo = 1>
   <cfreturn LOCAL.foo>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Evik. I over-simplified my example for clarity - now including the function call. The bug(?) is still present.

Comment: If you create a LOCAL scoped variable outside of a function, it becomes variables.LOCAL.